# How can I add the search Icon to the search bar in such way that the icon does not overlap the search input?

Tags: html, css, position

I have been learning html and css for 2 weeks now, as a challenge I tasked myself to create a product landing page.

I created a search bar and added a "search" icon but I couldn't position the icon in such way that it doesn't overlap the search input.

[image: The image]

The image^

The code: I apologise, I know it sucks

```
#search {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -150px;
  border-style: double;
}

#btn1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 410px;
  top: 35px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/D1dvJTV/icons8-search.gif") no-repeat top right;
  background-size: 23px auto;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

How can I make the icon stay in the search bar? Because another issue I am having is whenever I resize the page, the icon would move to a new position?

Comment: Please add your HTML with your question

Answer (score 1):

You can add a padding-right to your input to prevent text overlapping the search icon

```css
#search {
   border-radius: 20px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 1;
  outline: none;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

#search-input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#search-input-wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: 10px;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/D1dvJTV/icons8-search.gif") no-repeat center;
  background-size: 23px auto;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="search-input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="search">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Vineeth, cheers mate works great. I have a question what is the significance of addidng #search-input-wrapper, ie a container, everything else seems to works better?

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful. We add a wrapper container to encapsulate the elements. This way we can better control however we want. Another main reason I used a wrapper container is because I wanted to add the search icon using the ::after (psedo-selector) but unfortunately input does not support ::before & ::after selectors

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```css
.search-bar-container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  width: 95%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.icon {
  width: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-bar-container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
  <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
</div>
```

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/XWjPavP

Answer (score 0):

instead of using input and overlapping icon on it, wrap the input and icon in a tag like div, section, aside whichever one you want.

```css
.search-wrap {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 0.3em 1em;
}
#search {
  margin: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  height: 2em;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#btn1 {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/D1dvJTV/icons8-search.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  width: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="search-wrap">
      <input type="text" id="search" />
      <img id="btn1" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Nitesh, thanks for answering. I am wondering why did adding a container for the input makes everything works smoother?

Comment: When we add a container we also change image (position="relative"), so when position is not absolute the tag will cover its height and width and same goes for the input tag, hence image will not overlap to input and vice versa.